# Is that possible to grant any permission without asking to user?

Tags: android, android-permissions

I know this is not possible but this application do.......

https://www.snaptubeapp.com/

How that possible my device grant all permission to this application which application requires how , application never asking me to allow Read and Write storage permission and etc......then how its granted for this application

I don't know this is best platform this type of question all edits and suggestions are welcome

Comment: Is this a promotional post for snaptubeapp?

Comment: @PankajKumar no sir is not a promotional post for snaptube application my question is that how to  grant permission without asking to user ,  is not possible then how this application do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If the device is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or higher, and the
>   app's targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, the user isn't notified of any
>   app permissions at install time. Your app must ask the user to grant
>   the dangerous permissions at runtime. When your app requests
>   permission, the user sees a system dialog telling the user which
>   permission group your app is trying to access. The dialog includes a
>   Deny and Allow button. Read more at [Permissions overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview)

So I looked into their manifest and found a smart work there

Answer lies into the

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

They have `android:targetSdkVersion` as `22` into manifest.

You can DIY by using steps in Android Studio.

```
Build -> Analyse APK.. -> give downloaded apk path.
```

It will open apk, go to manifest file and see content.

---

And yes it would have some drawbacks also, but that would depend on the features you are using into your app. As [Nilesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7666442/nilesh-rathod) mentioned, you need to read [Best-Practices](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk).

---

And [you will not be able to push your application to play store](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html), if you do so. For few other drawbacks, you should read Nilesh's answer on the liked question.

Comment: is i am change in my `targetSdkVersion` in my gradle app module file then system never ask me to grant permision

Comment: **Suggestion** you might need to add this in your answer [Meet Google Play's target API level requirement](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk)

Comment: Correct. Since target version 23 it asks for permission granted by user. If target version is less than 23 it would be granted automatically.